# Apply style to nav ul li after in html not via css

Tags: html, css, nav

I have a `nav ul li:after` definition in a css like:

```
nav ul:not(.first) li:after {
    margin-left: 10px;
    content: '';
    color: #bbb;
}
```

But to get rid of the not(.first), because it is affecting other "nav" in the page...
I want to apply the properties to a specific `nav ul, li:after`, the others nav are fine, only this I want to apply this style:

```
 <nav>
    <ul>
        <li id="all">All</li>
        <li id="web">WEB</li>
        <li id="print">DesignD</li>
        <li id="illustration">Illustration</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Is it possible? How to do it?

Comment: Then give it a class name and target it directly. What's the problem?

Comment: but is it possible to do it directly in the code? can you post an example?

Comment: What does *directly in the code* mean? Don't you know how to add a class to an element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I'd suggest using the `style` attribute but sadly I doesnt really work with `:later`.
So as already mentioned you will have to work a class or an id and then targeting it in css.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure I know what your taking about, but forgive me if I'm wrong. You would like to apply those styles to just the first li?

In that case you should call out

```
nav ul:first-child li:after {
margin-left: 10px;
content: '';
color: #bbb;
}
```